# ElasticSearch: Query multiple AND with an OR only returning second half of query

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create an ElasticSearch query that reads like this: `(field1 == 1 && field2 != a) || (field3 == 2 && field4 != b)`

I've referenced other Stack Overflow and came with this json below:

```
{"query":{

  "bool":{

    "should": [{

      "bool":{

        "must":[{"term":{"field1":"1"}}],

        "must_not":[{"term":{"field2":"a"}}]

      },

      "bool":{

        "must":[{"term":{"field3":"3"}}],

        "must_not":[{"term":{"field4":"b"}}]

      }

    }]

  }}}
```

When I test to run the output, though, only the (field3 == 2 && field4 != b) part is queried.

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You have added both the `bool` clause in single element of `should`cluase. it should be 2 diffrent element in should cluase. Query will return documents if atleast one `bool` cluase match from `should` cluase.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "field1": "1"
                }
              }
            ],
            "must_not": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "field2": "a"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "field3": "3"
                }
              }
            ],
            "must_not": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "field4": "b"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**It should be something like below**:

[image]